# List all functions f: {a, b, c} → {0,1 }.

Tags: functions

This is a homework problem I have. Can someone just explains what it means, please? I can think of at least a dozen functions off the top of my head, but I think that's too many to be correct since we were asked to list them all.

Comment: It means exactly what it says. You have to write down every single possible function from $\{a, b, c\}$ to $\{0, 1\}$. There aren't that many.

Comment: Do you understand the notation in the problem? Have you been given a definition of "function" to use? (If it helps: there are exactly 2³ = 8 such functions.)

Comment: There are actually fewer than that, but you're close. You should list what you've thought of, so we can help you understand which are correct.

Comment: A more interesting question might be how may _relations_ are possible.  In this case, the number of relations should be $3^3 = 27$--because there are three possible assignments: $\{0\}$; $\{1\}$; or $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$.

Comment: @Jared: Why is that more interesting?

Comment: @Jared: There are $4^3 = 64$ relations. (You seem to be assuming that each of *a*, *b*, *c* must appear in at least one element of each relation, but that's not the case. A relation can be completely empty.)

Comment: @NikolajK Well the fact that I was wrong, suggests that it's a harder question--which I think it is.

Comment: @Jared: I doubt people who have the answer here straight know it because they have a perfect function space cardinality intuition. I'd say it suggest that the function space being called $Y^X$ is a good mnemonic. You also imply that a question being harder makes it more interesting, I'm dubious about that also.

Comment: @NikolajK I agree that arguing one problem is "harder" does not make it necessarily more interesting.  _However_ making one _think_ about relations (or maps) and how they are different from functions, I think _is_ interesting.

Answer (score 4):

You can consider a function to be a bit string of length three, i.e. $000$, $111$, $101$, etc.  This would define all possible assignments of $\{a,b,c,\}$ to $\{0, 1\}$ and there are indeed 8 possible functions:
\begin{align*}
 1.\ & f(x) = 0 \rightarrow f(a) = f(b) = f(c) = 0 &\longrightarrow 000\\
 2.\ & f(a) = 0, f(b) = 0, f(c) = 1 &\longrightarrow 001\\
 3.\ & f(a) = 0, f(b) = 1, f(c) = 0 &\longrightarrow 010\\
 4.\ & f(a) = 0, f(b) = 1, f(c) = 1 &\longrightarrow 011\\
 5.\ &  f(a) = 1, f(b) = 0, f(c) = 0 &\longrightarrow 100\\
 6.\ & f(a) = 1, f(b) = 0, f(c) = 1 &\longrightarrow 101\\
 7.\ & f(a) = 1, f(b) = 1, f(c) = 0 &\longrightarrow 110\\
 8.\ & f(x) = 1 \rightarrow f(a) = f(b) = f(c) = 1 &\longrightarrow 111
\end{align*}

Note that if you have a different problem then it can be framed the same way.  If you have $m$ objects in the domain and $n$ objects in the range, then you can create a length-m string for which each digit can take $n$ values.  This suggests that the answer is $n^m$ (since you have $n$ objects in the range by $m$ objects in the domain).

As a quick example, let's say you have $\{a, b, c, d\}\mapsto \{e, g, f\}$, then you have to create a string of length 4 and each digit can take on three different values, therefore is $3*3*3*3 = 3^4$

Comment: Oooooh thank you so much, I was misinterpreting the notation

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ and $B$ be two non empty sets with $m\ \text{and}\ n$ elements respectively. Then the number of functions from $A$ to $B$ is $n^m.$

here $A=\{a,b,c\}$ and $B=\{0,1\}.$ Then the number of functions from $A$ to $B$ is $2^3(=8).$

For, $f:A \rightarrow B$ to be a function, Every element in $A$ should have a unique image.

$a$ has 2 ways to be mapped, $b$ has 2 ways to be mapped and $c$ also has 2 ways to be mapped

Therefore  there are $2\times 2 \times 2$ functions from $ A \rightarrow B$.

Answer (score 0):

$f_1: f_1(\{a,b,c\}) = \{0\}$
$f_2: a \to 1, b \to 0, c \to 1$
$f_3: a \to 1, b \to 0, c \to 0$
$f_4: a \to 1, b \to 1, c \to 0$
$f_5: a \to 1, b \to 1, c \to 1$
$f_6: a \to 0, b \to 0, c \to 1$
....

$f_{8}: f_{8}(\{a,b,c\}) = \{1\}$.

It appears that there are a total of $8$ such functions.

Comment: There are eight such functions, not ten. (Or are you using octal?) By the way, you can include line-breaks in your answers by writing `<br>` or `<br />`, or by using a bulleted list.